# Extracting text using XPath in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have a problem with scraping a site.
I'm working in javaScript and was trying to use XPath to send my scraper the right direction.

I used FireBug to get the Xpath that I need.

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[9]/div/div
```

But I'm not sure if the xpath should go in the div where the paragraph is or directly in the paragraf?
And I also wonder what kind if information is return? Is the Node returned or is it the actuall text that I get back by using my function called

```
ZU.xpath(doc, '/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[9]/div/div');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to go directly in the paragraph to get the text 
see below and example

```
 $x('//*/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[9]/div/div/p/text()')
```

Comment: Okay, so something like this should work for me?

ZU.xpath(doc, '/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[9]/div/div/p/text()');